# How do you get the Bound g(n) of the graph?

Tags: asymptotics

We all know that We estimate our running time by drawing a graph and Big O and Big Theta is our worst and average running time respectively and we graph our function like :

$ O(g(n))= f(n)$ and create a range $0<f(n)<cg(n)$

and for $\Theta(g(n))$ $0<c_21g(n) <f(n)<c_2g(n)$

here What does g(n) means precisely and how do you get the value of g(n) ?
For example, for the Big O, What is the role of g(n) and what does it do ?

[image: Graph of Growth of function]
EDIT : Sorry, I wasn't able to write my problem clearly but I know you have somehow understood that what I was trying to explain.

My question/problem was we know that from growth of function of running time that for $O(g(n))= f(n)$, we have $0<f(n)<cg(n)$ and my question is What does it really mean by g(n) and why is it used here ? I have encountered this equation from a algo book but the writer didn't explain about g(x) nor it's usage. that's why I've asked my question here because I'm curious to know about the use of g(x) in that equation.

Comment: Your question is full of inaccuracies and wrong statements. I don't quite know what your question is, but I recommend that if you really want to understand the concepts here, start again from the very basics, skip nothing and ask a focused question when you feel unsure. Make sure you are also using a decent textbook or other material.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to write my problem clearly but I know you have somehow understood that what I was trying to explain. 

My question/problem was we know from growth of function of running time that for $O(g(n))= f(n)$, we have $0<f(n)<cg(n)$ and my question is What does it really mean by g(n) and why is it used here ? I have encountered this equation from a algo book but the writer didn't explain about g(x) nor it's usage. that's why I've asked my question here because I'm curious to know about the use of g(x) in that equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$ represents a function of $n$. Its value depends on the problem you are studying.

For example, consider the following algorithm:

```
Input: an integer array t of size n, an integer x
Ouput: a boolean, equal to true iif x is in t
for each element y in t do
    if x = y then
       return true
done
return false
```

In this algorithm, $n$ is the size of the given array, and it represents the *size of the problem*, meaning that the running time will depend on $n$ (at least if we consider integer arithmetic to be in constant time).

If $f(n)$ denotes the running time of the algorithm for an array of size $n$, then the algorithm analysis can show that
$$f(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n)$$
That means that $f(n) \in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$, with $g(n) = n$. We can't conclude that $f(n) \in \Theta(n)$, because the algorithm could take a constant time to return a value (for example if the first integer of the array is equal to $x$).

I suggest you read more content of your book(s) to understand correctly how to do an algorithm analysis.

Also, please note that $\mathcal{O}(g(n))$ or $\Theta(g(n))$ does not represent a function, but a set of functions. That's why it would be preferable to write $f(n) \in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ instead of $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$. At the least, choose $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ over $\mathcal{O}(g(n))=f(n)$.